# Why can't I add color using col = in my cat_plot?

Tags: r, plot

[image: Figure 1]

I am trying to make the lines in my cat_plot color blue. I have tried the following code, putting the col = next to the geom = c("line"):

```
library(interactions) 
Figure01 <- cat_plot(M1, pred = "OA_status", geom = c("line", col = "blue"), interval = TRUE, 
        x.label = 'OA Status', y.label = 'Predicted Altmetric Score', 
        main.title = 'Figure 1')
Figure01
```

But I am only getting the attached picture. As you can see, the lines are not blue in this plot.  Where am I going wrong— is the col = in the wrong place? Or is the color argument not applicable for this type of plot?

Comment: Can you specify which package `cat_plot` comes from? It isn't a standard inclusion.

Comment: cat_plot is from library (interactions)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `diamonds` dataset as an example. You need to use `colors` instead of `col`. What you can do is depending on the number of factors is adding blue to your plot like this:

```
library(interactions)
library(ggplot2)
fit <- lm(price ~ cut * color, data = diamonds)
cat_plot(fit, pred = color, modx = cut, interval = TRUE, geom = "line", colors = c(rep("blue", 5)))
```

Output:

[image]